# How to link to a filter result page?

Tags: magento2.2

Is this possible to link a image to magento 2.2 filter result page, the page is such as you filter price amount (100$ - 500$), I just want to link a image to this filter result page, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can add static block with image having link to filter page something like :

```
<a href="{{store direct_url="gear/bags.html?price=100-500"}}"><img src="image.jpg"/></a>
```

then either call using layout or any cms page.